# Angular HttpClientModule error

Tags: angular, http, atom-editor

I am new to Angular, was trying the service http. But I came across this problem. Do you guys know what has gone wrong? Thanks

[image]

from the terminal, the error stated is

[image]

According to the error message, I went to module.d.ts file

[image]

---

---

Thanks to you guys, i have changed it to HttpClient and the redline disappear, but I still got the error from terminal. and the page is still not showing.
[image]

[image]

---

---

For anyone came across the error message in terminal, the HttpClientModule class in module.d.ts should be empty. I added it accidentally throught code suggestion by typescript. Thanks for all the amazing helps[image]

Comment: Not related at all, but what theme do you use? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `HttpClient`. That's what's used to make the AJAX Calls,

To use `HttpClient` though, you'll have to add the HttpClientModule to your `imports` array of the `NgModule`

So it should be in your service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class ProductService {
  private productUrl = 'api/products/products.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getProducts() {
    ...
  }
}
```

And this in your Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule ],
  declarations: [ /*Your Components Here*/ ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here's a [Stackblitz Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-modal) to help you out with it.

Comment: Thanks! I just changed that to HttpClient, but I still got the same error message from the CLI, should I changed the module.d.ts file too?

Comment: Thanks, could you help taking a look again? I have added a new picture just now :)

Comment: Did you change `HttpClientModule` to `HttpClient` in your Service constructor?  `constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}`

Comment: Did you make any changes to `module.d.ts`?

Comment: Try restarting the server.

Comment: I think I will try to delete node_module and reinstall again. Thanks a lot for you help! since the httpClient problem had solved, I will mark this question solved :)

Comment: Great. Please Ask Another Question if your problem still persists. Happy Coding! :)

Comment: problem solved! :) (after reinstall the node_modules)! thanks! Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

import `HttpClient`

> In app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

imports:[HttpClientModule]
```

> component.ts / service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http:HttpClient){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using the `HttpClientModule` inside your service file, you should be using the `HttpClient` class instead. The `HttpClientModule` should be imported into your `app.module.ts` file, see below:

`app.module.ts`

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [..., HttpClientModule, ..],
  ...
})
```

`*.service.ts`

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

...

constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
  const productUrl: '...';

  this.http.get<IProduct[]>(productUrl).pipe(
    tap(...),
    catchError(...)
  );
}
```